# Better way of marking a location for an object to copy

Tags: animation, rigging, transforms, parent

[image: This is the setup]

In the picture you can see LH and RH these two circles mark where the IK markers(you can see the Right hand IK it is a sphere) for my hands and arms go. These circles are put exactly where they need to go for the hand with the pose I have saved to hold everything without clipping.

Problem is I can not align the hands to the markers because the loc rot data seems to be different. It seems like the bones have some sort of local loc rot data. I tried putting the markers on the rig instead but I used a child of constraint and it maid my object hierarchy way too messy because with 20 of these guys it is confusing. Also that did not solve the issue with my left hand

I currently think I could make a pose to get everything set up then apply my child of constraints so that everything is working. That goes like this

- rifle use child constraint to the right wrist.
- left wrist is child constraint to the LH circle.

When everything is aligned it works perfect but getting it aligned is irritating because I have to do it manually. now imagine doing reload animations and doping the gun and it is just a mess. So is there a good way to automatically do all of this?

Comment: Please clarify you question showing more screen captures with the hand armature in different bone render, perhaps octahedral, in the defective position and correct position.  The lines are difficult to see.

Comment: How exacting/demanding are you being for hand placement?  Extremely demanding so the a closeup view would look correct.  Or no closeups so you can accept a more casual approach?

Comment: I know you took a lot of time to write the words and I think you can still clarify your question.

Comment: Please show heirarchical parent child relationships in outliner window.

Comment: I can do all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion.  Try a more casual approach if that is acceptable.

- I believe no part of the wrist bone should touch the visible gun. The wrist  placement need not be in the mesh of the gun.   The placement could be near the gun.  See the abstract control note below. The wrist bone maybe able to be specified head to tail for placement.
- You might introduce a gun contact bone non deforming if that suits you.
- Consider a [track to] constraint. To control wrist bone or connected bone.
- You may need to worry about cyclic dependencies.  Whether real or Blender defect.  You may need to have non rendered abstract effector to control both the placement of gun and the hands.The abstract effector could be a simple armature with bones for the left and right wrist placement and location and rotation of gun.   This may eliminate cyclic dependencies if they arise.
- Currently your question does not show the hierarchical relationships or parent child relationships.
- The placement of fingers tips can just be curled.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a very simple way of fixing this. Because of the fact that I really need the animations to look good up close the level of detail needs to be there. So here is the solution step by step.

note this only works with a proper IK rig set up. and even then my IK is not exactly normal.

Place the gun in the hand of the character.
create a circle mesh with a child of constraint that applies to the right wrist. copy the rotation and location of the gun to it. 
then to clear up hierarchies give it an object keep transform parent to the character in this case it is a circle at their feet.(note that if this is not done after the child of constraint things will get buggy for some reason.)
[image]

pose the fingers to line up correctly and give the gun a child of constraint that applies to the right wrist.
Create a pose that puts the gun into the offhand 
Then save that pose.
Whenever you need to give the character a gun. All you have to do is.
Copy the location rotation data of the circle on it's right hand to the gun. 
Give the gun a child of constraint that links it to some consent bone on the hand in my case the Right hand wrist works fine.
Apply the saved pose in my case it is called gun setup.
this puts the left hand in the forward position.
give the left hand IK controller a child of constraint that applies to the gun. Make sure to set the inverse.
now you have both hands connected to the gun and to aim it or change the pose all you have to do is rotate and translate the right hand IK controller.
And to disconnect the gun from the character all you have to do is set the child of constraints influence to 0.